Greek letters in Rstudio, and exporting to csv
I'm reading data from pdf files that contains Greek letters, and it imports as unicode.  I want it to:
a) display correctly as Greek letters in RStudio, and
b) maintain the correctly formatted Greek letters when exporting to csv files.
I have some code that successfully converts the unicode to Greek:
> stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("<U\\+(....)>","\\\\u\\1", c('<U+03B1>','<U+03B2>','<U+03B3>','<U+03B4>')))

This produces the desired result:
1 "α" "β" "γ" "δ"
But, as soon as I try to put this into a data frame (or data table, or tibble), it no longer displays correctly:
> data.frame(greek=stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("<U\\+(....)>","\\\\u\\1", c('<U+03B1>','<U+03B2>','<U+03B3>','<U+03B4>'))))
     greek
1        a
2        ß
3 <U+03B3>
4        d

On the other hand, if I View() the data.frame, it again displays correctly in the view window:
> View(data.table(greek=stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("<U\\+(....)>","\\\\u\\1", c('<U+03B1>','<U+03B2>','<U+03B3>','<U+03B4>')))))


I need to firstly get the required output into the data frame correctly (my actual data is chemical analysis data, so the Greek letters form parts of the chemical names, eg α-pinene, etc). The objective then is to export to a csv file that can be opened in Excel with the Greek letters displayed correctly.
Any assistance would be much appreciated.

I think this is dependent on the system and the R environment you are using. I can see the data.frame example printed to the screen fine in R+emacs and RGui on Windows 10 for instance.

Also prints fine on Ubuntu/R4.4.0.

I can confirm the Greek text renders correctly in an xlsx file using
library(stringi)
library(openxlsx)
df <- data.frame(greek=stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("<U\\+(....)>","\\\\u\\1", c('<U+03B1>','<U+03B2>','<U+03B3>','<U+03B4>'))))
write.xlsx(df, "greek.xlsx")

> packageVersion("stringi")
[1] ‘1.8.4’
> packageVersion("openxlsx")
[1] ‘4.2.5.2’
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1


Okay yes the openxlsx export works correctly on my platform too.  I wonder what it does differently to the base write.csv function.  I will mark this as the accepted answer if no one comes forward with a .csv approach since it will work for this specific purpose, although for storing larger data sets I prefer .csv files.

I'm assuming that the problem is an encoding mismatch based on what you are trying to write versus how the encoding is being interpreted.
macOS and most modern Linux distros default to UTF-8. Although Windows uses Unicode, terminals and consoles have compatibility layers for legacy codepages. I find explicitly declaring the encoding to be a useful approach.
write_csv will tend to default to the system encoding, but on Windows legacy comparability layers can cause complexities. A bare bones write.csv will work if your ecosystem is all UTF-8,  but can fail when that isn't the case. The following all work for me:
library(stringi)
df <- data.frame(greek=stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("<U\\+(....)>","\\\\u\\1", c('<U+03B1>','<U+03B2>','<U+03B3>','<U+03B4>'))))
write.csv(df, 'test1.csv')

conn<-file('test3.csv',encoding="UTF-8")
write.csv(df, conn)

write.csv(df, 'test2.csv',fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')

library(readr)
write_csv(df, 'test4.csv')

write_csv by default always uses UTF-8.
